# Problema en programación C, lista simple sin cabecera

Tags: c

Buenas tardes, estoy haciendo un programa (práctica universidad), donde añadir,mostrar,borrar, etc 'estructuras clientes para una agencia de viajes'. 
Estoy utilizando listas simples sin cabecera.

Cuando lo ejecuto, elijo en el menú añadir cliente nuevo, lo añade pero cuando pasa a la siguiente función para poner **NULL** en el ultimo elemento de la lista.El programa se detiene.
Alguien me podría ayudar? muchas gracias de antemano!

El error me sale en la linea while de esta fución:

```
struct NodoCliente *ListaUltima(struct NodoCliente *l){

    struct NodoCliente *aux;    /*El ultimo elemento de la lista es NULL.*/
    aux = l;

    while ( aux->siguiente != NULL ){
        aux = aux->siguiente;
    }
    return (aux);
}
```

Aqui dejo el código completo:

```
struct Viaje {
    char identificador[DNI_MAX + 3]; //Identificador compuesto por      DNI_identificaror unico (Ej: 75499435J_02)
    char ciudad_destino[CIUDAD_DESTINO_MAX];
    char hotel[HOTEL_MAX];
    int num_noches;
    char transporte[TRANSPORTE_MAX];
    float precio_aloj;
    float precio_desp;
};

struct Cliente {
    char dni[DNI_MAX];
    char nombre[NOMBRE_MAX];
    char apellidos[APELLIDOS_MAX];
    char direccion[DIRECCION_MAX];
    int num_viajes;
    struct Viaje viaje[VIAJES_MAX];
    struct Cliente *ptrcliente;
};


struct NodoCliente {
    char dni[DNI_MAX];
    char nombre[NOMBRE_MAX];
    char apellidos[APELLIDOS_MAX];
    char direccion[DIRECCION_MAX];
    struct NodoCliente *siguiente;
};

typedef struct NodoCliente *ListaClientes;
typedef struct NodoCliente *Posicion;

struct NodoCliente* crearListaClientes(void)
    {
        return (NULL);
    }

struct NodoCliente* posicionPrimero(struct NodoCliente *l)
    {
        return (l);
    }

struct NodoCliente* insertarCliente(struct NodoCliente *l, struct NodoCliente      *pindice){

FILE *fc; //Declaramos un putero a File

char nombre_fichero[NOMBRE_FICHERO_MAX];
char dni[DNI_MAX];
char nombre[NOMBRE_MAX];
char apellidos[APELLIDOS_MAX];
char direccion[DIRECCION_MAX];

struct NodoCliente *aux;

aux = (struct NodoCliente *) malloc(sizeof(struct NodoCliente));

printf("Introduzca el nombre del fichero del cliente a crear: ");
fflush(stdin);
scanf("%s",nombre_fichero);
printf("Extrayendo informacion del archivo %s\n", nombre_fichero);
fc = fopen(nombre_fichero,"r");

if (fc == NULL) {
    printf("Archivo no encontrado.\n");
}

else {

    fscanf(fc,"%[^\n] %[^\n] %[^\n] %[^\n]", dni, nombre, apellidos, direccion);

    //fclose(fc);

    printf("Creando cliente con datos: \n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n", dni, nombre, apellidos, direccion);


    if (aux != NULL) {

        strcpy(aux->dni, dni);
        strcpy(aux->nombre, nombre);
        strcpy(aux->apellidos, apellidos);
        strcpy(aux->direccion, direccion);

        if (l == NULL) {

            aux->siguiente = NULL;
            l = aux;

        }else {

            aux->siguiente = pindice->siguiente;
            pindice->siguiente = aux;

        }
    }
}

return(l);
}

struct NodoCliente *ListaUltima(struct NodoCliente *l){

struct NodoCliente *aux;    /*El ultimo elemento de la lista es NULL.*/
aux = l;

while ( aux->siguiente != NULL ){
    aux = aux->siguiente;
}
return (aux);
}


void mostrar_lista(struct NodoCliente *l) {

struct NodoCliente *aux; /* lo usamos para recorrer la lista */
int i;
i=0;
aux = l;

printf("\nMostrando la lista completa:\n");

while (aux!=NULL) {
    printf( "DNI: %s, Nombre: %s\n", aux->dni,aux->nombre);
    aux = aux->siguiente;
    i++;
}
if (i==0) printf( "\nLa lista está vacía!!\n" );
}

int main(){
int opcion;
ListaClientes listaclientes = crearListaClientes();
Posicion p1 = posicionPrimero(listaclientes);

do {
    printf ("Bienvenido, eliga una opción. ,\n\n");
    printf ("1- Dar de alta un nuevo cliente. \n");
    printf ("2- Dar de baja un cliente existente. \n");
    printf ("3- Dar de alta un nuevo viaje. \n");
    printf ("4- Eliminar un viaje. \n");
    printf ("5- Listar datos de la agencia. \n");
    printf ("6- Escribir en un fichero los datos de la agencia. \n");
    printf ("7- Deshacer acción. \n");
    printf ("8- Rehacer acción. \n");
    printf ("9- Salir. \n\n");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf ("%d", &opcion);
    printf ("\n");

    switch (opcion) {
        case 1:
            insertarCliente(listaclientes, p1);
            p1 = ListaUltima(listaclientes);

            break;
```

Comment: Sin ánimo de ofender ni menospreciar tu trabajo, pero, ¿ has intentado depurarlo ? ¿ En que circunstancias se produce el error ? Al introducir el primer elemento, siempre, al añadir al final, al insertar no al final, ... unos `printf( "%p", ... )` colocados en los sitios adecuados hacen mucho. Acotan el problema.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, pues si, he intentado, el error me da justamente en el "while ( aux->siguiente != NULL )" de la función *ListaUltima.

Comment: No es una respuesta, es un comentario. ¿ El error se produce justo la primera vez que pulsas alguna opción ? Es decir, **al crear la lista**, o la creas bien y se produce al añadir nuevos elementos ? Lo que intento es que veas la lógica a seguir para futuras ocasiones.

Comment: Normalmente, cuando el error está suficientemente acotado, la solución sale sola :-)

Comment: Recientemente, ha surgido una [pregunta en Meta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2146/23371) sobre las líneas a seguir en este tipo de preguntas. Línea con la que estoy de acuerdo.  Esta pregunta no cumple, por le menos, con uno de los requisitos: líneas de código mínimas e imprescindibles para reproducir el problema.

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque no cumple con los requisitos de las solicitudes de depuración.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias a todos por vuestra ayuda :)